# How to know the previous route in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i'm using react-navigation 2.x.x and i wanted to know if it's possible to know the previous route name ? I want to redirect the user with a `goback` if he's been to a certain page.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You could use `history`: `console.log(this.props.history)`

Comment: You can use this.props.navigation.goBack(); just check  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/navigating/#going-back

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the previous screen like

```
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

You can access the route index with name [Navigation State](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/custom-navigators/#navigation-state)